# Sørensen-Dice coefficient equivalence

Tags: combinatorics

I'm working on a open source custom NLP engine: https://github.com/nicrusso7/Mistyca (source code coming soon!). Trying to figure out some similarity measures, I wrote this formula (SIM) used to compare the similarity of two sets:

$SIM = 1 - \frac{|A-B|+|B-A|}{|A|+|B|}$

I'm trying a to prove that this formula is equivalent to the Sørensen-Dice coefficient:

$\frac{2|A∩B|}{|A|+|B|} = \frac{|A|+|B|-|A-B|-|B-A|}{|A|+|B|}$

Can anyone help me to demonstrate that?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you try to write SIM as one fraction?

Comment: I'm not sure of all the passages..

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Question (lke this) that doesn't show the author's own work/thoughts are typically unpopular here. Please edit the question to include that. I'll offer the following hint: $A\cap B=B\cap A$.

Comment: Thank you @Henrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words, you want to prove $|A|+|B|-|A-B|-|B-A|=2|A\cap B|$. This follows from $|A\cap B|=|A|-|A-B|=|B|-|B-A|$.